# What is the most efficient way to iterate in [false, true]?

Tags: rust, boolean, iteration, combinations

I have a function `foo` that takes 3 booleans, and I would want to get the result of this function with every combination of bools.

Here is how I did it:

```rust
fn foo(b1: bool, b2: bool, b3: bool) -> bool {
    b1 && b2 || !b3
}

fn main() {
    for b1 in vec![false, true] {
        for b2 in vec![false, true] {
            for b3 in vec![false, true] {
                println!("{} {} {} -> {}", b1, b2, b3, foo(b1, b2, b3));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a more direct/ shorter way to do it than creating a vector and then iterate through it?

Is there a way to do it with macros or with mutable functions, so that the compiler just go through each case without iterating?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use the [`itertools`](https://crates.io/crates/itertools) crate and then use the [`iproduct!()`](https://docs.rs/itertools/0.9.0/itertools/macro.iproduct.html) macro.

```rust
use itertools::iproduct;

fn main() {
    const FT: &[bool; 2] = &[false, true];

    for (&b1, &b2, &b3) in iproduct!(FT, FT, FT) {
        println!("{} {} {} -> {}", b1, b2, b3, foo(b1, b2, b3));
    }
}
```

Not saying it's "more efficient", but it is shorter to write.

Answer (score 6):

At the very least you can use arrays instead of vectors and thus save the dynamic allocations:

```
fn foo(b1: bool, b2: bool, b3: bool) -> bool {
  b1 && b2 || !b3
}

fn main() {
  for b1 in &[false, true] {
    for b2 in &[false, true] {
      for b3 in &[false, true] {
        println!("{} {} {} -> {}", 
                 b1, b2, b3,
                 foo(*b1, *b2, *b3));
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then you can save on loop nesting by using [`itertools::iproduct!`](https://docs.rs/itertools/0.9.0/itertools/macro.iproduct.html):

```
use itertools::iproduct; // 0.9.0

fn foo(b1: bool, b2: bool, b3: bool) -> bool {
  b1 && b2 || !b3
}

fn main() {
  for (&b1, &b2, &b3) in iproduct!(&[false, true], &[false, true], &[false, true]) {
    println!("{} {} {} -> {}", 
             b1, b2, b3,
             foo(b1, b2, b3));
  }
}
```

[(playground)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=d242760a5de575316ca6d9e46387991e)

Comment: Either I'm blind, or your answer didn't include `itertools` when I posted mine. If it did, I'll happily delete my answer :)

Comment: @vallentin I think I edited that in while you were writing yours

Answer (score 4):

Ideally you'd write `for b1 in [false, true]`, but that's [not yet possible](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/65819).

Even without it, you can do better than allocating and consuming a `Vec` - for example, you can iterate over an array slice:

```
for &b1 in &[false, true] {
    for &b2 in &[false, true] {
        for &b3 in &[false, true] {
            ...
```

Note that the pattern specifies a reference (which *dereferences* the matched value) because iterating over a slice of `T` doesn't produce actual `T` values, but `&T` references to values that reside in the slice.

To iterate directly over a fixed small number of values, you can use `std::iter::once()` and `chain()`:

```
for b1 in std::iter::once(false).chain(std::iter::once(true)) {
    ...
```

The above can be made slightly shorter by (mis)using `Option`, which is also iterable:

```
for b1 in Some(false).into_iter().chain(Some(true)) {
    ...
```

Answer (score 3):

There's no need to overcomplicate things. You can just do:

```
fn main() {
    for i in 0..=0b111 {
        let a = (i & 1) == 1;
        let b = (i >> 1 & 1) == 1;
        let c = (i >> 2 & 1) == 1;
        println!("{} {} {} -> {}", a, b, c, foo(a, b, c));
    }
}
```

Comment: I was thinking the same thing, but I'd probably use `let a = (i & 1) != 0; let b = (i & 2) !=0; let c = (i & 4) != 0;` As that makes it cealr the first case is not special in some way. I guess you could equally write the first as  `let a = (i >> 0 & 1 ) == 1;`

Comment: I'm not sure how this is any simpler than the original code - it requires the reader to study individual bit operations to even understand what the code is trying to do! The original was perhaps less clever, but definitely simpler and more understandable.

Comment: Depends on your background, I guess. I find this answer to be more straightforward and less error-prone than the original because it involves less repetition and nesting.

Comment: Nice low-level solution ! It's less mathematically satisfying but it's scalable, efficient and  it doesn't require a crate